# A chess question of W.T. Tutte

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ho.history-overview, combinatorial-game-theory

In *"Graph theory as I have known it"*, [p.12, Knights Errant](https://books.google.com/books?id=uYW2tttqQ74C&pg=PA12), the late Tutte mentions as an aside the chess question *"Does either Black or White have a certain win from the initial position,  given perfect play by both sides"*.

Is there any literature on that possibility of a black win, that is the possibility of the initial chess position being mutual zugzwang? What is the earliest reference to the question?

EDIT:
If posed in chess.stackexchange, the community might give an answer based on chess strategy. However the question of evaluating chess has a venerable mathematical tradition, including non-trivial work by Zermelo, Shannon & Elkies. So the intention of posting here in math.overflow is to ask from a purely mathematical perspective, e.g. what has combinatorial game theory to say?

Comment: I do not know the earliest reference to the question - I've wondered about it myself - but I believe this question is far, far outside the realm of current computational techniques and power. I just don't think there is anything even on the horizon that would make answering this question tractable.

Comment: This looks like a chess question, not a math question. Also, it's quite well-known. Whenever someone asks whether chess is close to solved, one of the responses is that we don't even know that black doesn't have a forced win. 

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a chess question and not really a math question.

Comment: Now that this interesting math question popped on the front page: do we know black doesn't win with just the rooks, say? Is there work on these "obvious" questions?

Comment: Oh I guess I just have enough points to see it. Darn

Comment: I asked Hikaru Nakamura this question several years ago, and his answer was essentially "of course it's a draw".

Comment: @Henry.L: Removing the "chess" tag was not, in my opinion, a good edit. I dislike "edit wars", therefore I shall not roll it back, but I believe that it harms the question rather than help it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question "does either Black or White have a certain win from the initial position, given perfect play by both sides" was first addressed by Wilhelm Steinitz in his 1896 "Theory of Perfect Play" (Chapter 6 of [Modern Chess Instructor](https://www.archive.org/details/modernchessinstr00steirich)). He concluded that "by proper play on both sides the legitimate issue of a game ought to be a draw".

You can find a quite detailed overview of the literature since Steinitz in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-move_advantage_in_chess). The advantages of Black over White seem to be largely psychological ("underdog").

Comment: Actually, if you look at opening databases, and condition on games being decisive (that is, not a draw), black seems to be running a massive disadvantage, so the underdog thing is of limited benefit, it seems...

Comment: The reference cited in this answer does not address the question posed.

Comment: Just to be clear, the results of practical play are not relevant to the question of the theoretical status of a Black win. 

Comment: For that matter, I highly doubt one could prove using current techniques that from the initial position with Black's queen removed, that Black has no win. Doing so would, in fact, be a major advance in the state of the art.

Comment: Almost everyone who plays competitive chess would view White as having some practical advantage over Black, other thins being equal. Well, maybe Adorjan would disagree...

Comment: I think those who disagree are being contrary, often because this will let them win a funny game against a weaker player. There is a prop in backgammon: What is more valuable, holding the doubling cube or getting an opening double 1? The correct answer is that the opening 1-1 gives a larger advantage. However, people will bet money to play out the position holding the cube, but only against weaker players whose mistakes in the rest of the game will easily make up for picking the side with the advantage.

Comment: This answer comes from a purely chess-playing perspective, not a mathematical perspective, and should never have been marked as correct. The question (at least in its current form) is capable of a proper mathematical response

Comment: Wasn't that already the opinion of French Enlightenment-era players, long before Steinitz? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait%C3%A9_des_Amateurs

Comment: @HAHelfgott Yes, that's right (and one wonders whether they were the first, too!), so saying Steinitz "first addressed" this question seems dubious. Perhaps Steinitz developed some further theory to back up these claims?

Answer (score 19):

In the German chess problem magazine *feenschach*, Heft 214 Band XXIV, July-August 2015 pp 178-180, I pose & solve the following mathematical puzzle: "Consider the 25 chess positions deriving from the 25 sequences of moves of the following form: 1. e4 e5 2. B~ B~. (I.e. two bishops are developed.) Show that at most *six* of these positions are wins for Black."

E.g. one position out of the 25 is:

[[image: one of 25 positions]]

This is solved *non-constructively* with a simple strategy-stealing argument, which places an upper bound on the possible number of Black wins as 25/4. However, I don't think this fragile approach can be generalized to the Holy Grail of showing that chess is not a win for Black. The population of 5x5 (or more generally nxn) positions examined here is kind of a best case, where there is maximal stealing possible. If one considers e.g. the population of 400 positions after Black's first move, then then we can show that at most 304/400 can be wins for Black. This is a much higher proportion, and shows the limitations of the approach.

27/12/2015: After the closing of this question for allegedly not being mathematical, I added the following to emphasize that it can very well be interpreted mathematically.

Thanks very much, Mr Calvert, for your support. I was a bit bemused that the question was suddenly closed for allegedly not being mathematical immediately **after** I posted an entirely mathematical response. The underlying article has simple lemmas and everything :-) Whether Black wins chess may be addressed by chess players in terms of chess strategy. Indeed the accepted answer here is such an opinion! However my interest is only mathematical.

Claude Shannon wrote in his well-known 1950 paper (Philosophical Magazine, Ser.7, Vol. 41, No. 314 - March 1950. XXII. Programming a Computer for Playing Chess)

"It is interesting that a slight change in the rules of chess gives a game for which it is provable that White has at least a draw in the initial position. Suppose the rules the same as those of chess except that a player is not forced to move a piece at his turn to play, but may, if he chooses, 'pass'."

I was really looking for partial strategy-stealing solutions, in the spirit of Shannon, but in ordinary chess. So for White to lose a tempo takes at least two moves. Interestingly, parity concerns are particularly significant in the chess starting array.

In "More Games of No Chance" by MSRI (= "*Mathematical* Sciences Research Institute") Publications, Volume 42, 2002, Unsolved Problems in Combinatorial Games #29, [p 465](https://books.google.com/books?id=WNVmb5ht-oMC&pg=PA465), the *mathematician* Richard Guy also raised the question whether chess could be a Black win. However he misstated the result that I had emailed him. The correct result has only now been published (feenschach, above).

Another possible angle of attack, given that chess is so hard, is to ask what properties a simpler symmetric positional combinatorial game would have to satisfy to offer non-trivial strategy-stealing. Intuitively, Zugzwang is a feature in cold positions, but the chess in the opening appears to be hot. What other games can one set up so that e.g. a two-move tempo loss can exist, without being apparently as (literally!) self-defeating as in chess.

As this mathematical question remains incorrectly closed - I'm happy to discuss this with anyone offline: there is an email contact given at the bottom of http://anselan.com/chess.html.

Comment: It is sad that this comment,  from a new poster, will not be more widely seen in view of the later "put on hold" decision.

Comment: It is sad that this poster has chosen to insult other users of the site. The rudeness in the last paragraph has no place here.

Comment: I wondered whether my mildly cheeky remark would provoke someone to actually respond. I have of course removed this clause immediately. Please can you exercise similar enthusiasm to lobby to actually fix the incorrect classification of this question.

Comment: I suspect the real reason for closing the question is not that it isn't mathematical but that it's notorious. Everyone has heard of it, no one has any idea how to solve it, so there's not much point discussing it. You might get much the same reaction if you asked whether there's any literature on the possibility of Goldbach's Conjecture being false. By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Comment: If it's an open problem, according to https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic it should apparently be tagged as such and sent to the community wiki (whatever that is). In fact, the question was a literature search. So what to do now?

Comment: You can post to https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/223/requests-for-reopen-and-undelete-votes-for-on-hold-closed-and-deleted-question and make the case for reopening.

Comment: What does "L~" mean? From the fact that there are 25 possibilities I'm guessing that it's knight moves, but in algebraic notation in English the letter N is used for a knight.

Comment: @PeterTaylor "L" stands for Läufer, which is bishop. Sorry about failing to translate. I've fixed. The other German pieces are König, Dame, Turm, Springer and Bauer. Please have a go at this puzzle, then you can see where I am trying to go with this question

Comment: @GerryMyerson. And another year has passed. This has been an object lesson to me about the difficulties in getting anyone to read what someone has actually written, rather than skipping to a preconception about what they must be saying. Have you figured out the solution to the 2 bishops problem? Isn't it interesting that the number N = 25/4 emerges? What would it take in a game's structure for this kind of reasoning to suffice to solve the entire game? If N dipped below the number of White choices, then there would be a White move which denies Black a win. Or is this impossible?

Comment: My guess is that there must be some kind of "consistency protection theorem" which implies you can't use this kind of strategy stealing in loopy games to prove that the second player does not have a win. Surely someone must have looked at this already?

Comment: The number of Black wins, whatever it may be, is a whole number. $25/4=6.25$ is not. If $25/4$ is an upper bound for the number of Black wins, then so is $13/2$, and so is $2\pi$, and $\sqrt{37}$. So, to me, it's not "interesting that the number $N=25/4$ emerges," rather, it's a sign that you and I are not on the same page.

Comment: @Gerry thanks for your response. I hope you can "move to my page".  25/4 is one upper bound (there's another) for the 2 bishops game. How about the set of 49 positions 1. a4 a5 2. Ra3 Ra6 3. R~ R~? This approach won't solve chess, but I do suspect that there should be a general result about *why* this kind of approach is not able to prove that a symmetric loopy game is not a second player win. I showed this problem to Elwyn Berlekamp a long time ago, and he thought it was cool, but had no idea either how to generalize

Comment: Sorry, still not on your page. If $25/4$ is an upper bound, then there isn't just one other upper bound; every real number greater than $25/4$ is another upper bound. And any real number strictly between $6$ and $7$ is another, equally sharp upper bound.

Comment: If each player has n choices (here 5) then there are two upper bounds, both of which are functions of n. For most n, (n^2/4) is the larger, but for some it's the other bound. These two functions emerge from the graph theory.

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself, IF YOU WANT TO BE SURE I SEE A COMMENT INTENDED FOR ME, YOU HAVE TO PUT @GERRY IN IT.

Answer (score 1):

In my decade of chess-playing, I have never come across anything remotely resembling an answer to this question. If the perfect play question had already been answered by example, chess would be an exercise in memorization -- the absolute perfect path(s) of the game could all be played out down to the endgame, and whoever deviates first loses material. In the event that one side has a forced win, the other side would always be the one forced to lose material. Brute-forcing a solution to chess is nowhere near possible at the moment, given the amount of possible game positions (~ $10^{43}$, according to Claude Shannon). I've never heard of any sound way to argue this question other than brute-force.

Comment: That $10^{43}$ excludes promotions. 

Comment: Why the definite article before "perfect play"? It's imaginable that either e4 or d4 (for example) can be the opening move of a "perfectly played game (and similarly, for many positions, it's imaginable that there is no one best move). Actually, when I was more active in chess, I used to like opening with Nf3 as White, and it's not clear to me that that is inferior to e4 or d4. 

Comment: I believe the meaning is 

    the "perfect play question"

not

    "the perfect play" question

Comment: Ah, thanks Lee. Happily, I see "path(s)" in the next line, so this would support that reading as well. 

Comment: I've heard of a GrandMaster contend that "White wins with Queen's Pawn".  I forget the name though.  Almost everyone in the chess world, however, thinks the game, with best play, is a draw - if they had to say.  Virtually no one would contend that Black would win.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually no one in the Chess world believes Black wins, hence no literature on what you highlight.

Of course, that isn't mathematical proof, but if we were to ever get an answer and I had to gamble on it, I'd say it's a draw with optimal play.

Now if we look at stats, certainly Black loses more often than white loses, with draws becoming more common at higher levels of play.

I'd even say if White got 2 moves to start, and the moves were one for one thereafter, the game is a draw with optimal play.  Granted, Black would be cramped by White's first two moves.