# Strategy-stealing in chess

Tags: reference-request, combinatorial-game-theory, chess

> Is it proved that white can guarantee at least draw in chess?

A while ago I was told that it was proved using [strategy-stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy-stealing_argument), but I cannot find a reference.

**Postscript.** Please accept my apology --- most likely there is no such theorem, otherwise the reference would be already founded.

Comment: I am almost sure that it is not proved. There are quite subtle positions with mutual zugzwang, and why not the initial one?

Comment: @FedorPetrov maybe actual formulation included zugzwang somehow.

Comment: There is a known problem in which the stealing strategy works: chess in which each move consists of two usual moves. Then White may steal the strategy by Kc3+Kb1, although unlikely this helps you to draw against very good chess player

Comment: @FedorPetrov I am sure that it was about ordinary chess, and it was told by a mathematician who is also a professional chess player.   By the way, I no longer see a problem with zugzwang.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Can you briefly describe why you no longer see a problem with zugzwang? It seems to me that if the zugzwang obstacle is resolved, the rest of the argument should follow quite easily.

Comment: The entire premise of strategy stealing arguments is in the context where being a move ahead is beneficial. In chess, it is not always the case, and this is illustrated by zugzwangs.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Might you mean Nc3? Kc3 would be the king, not the knight.

Comment: @Wojowu see the comments in the answer of ckefa.

Comment: @user, which letter stands for which piece may depend on what language you learned your chess in.

Comment: Maybe there's a reason, Anton, why you can't find a reference.

Comment: @GerryMyerson good question --- the friend who told me this, is on vacation, after searching for a couple of hours, I thought that MO will find a ref in a few minutes. It might happen that I misunderstood the statement (it was a few years ago).

Comment: @user44191 ah, of course Nc3+Nb1, sorry. (In Russian Knight and King also both start with К, but notation К is for the Knight.)

Comment: Anton, is not "White can at least draw" just equivalent to "initial position is not a mutual zugzwang"?

Comment: @FedorPetrov right.

Comment: Only if both sides make two moves instead of one has the game been proven to be at least a draw for white.

Comment: Suppose on the contrary white cannot guarantee at least draw i.e. there exists a winning strategy for black. Then... (probably one of those copy position zugzwang things?)

Comment: @GerryMyerson Huh, I would've thought that the notation would be the same across languages (though obviously influenced by the original language choice), as otherwise that kinda defeats the purpose of the notation (as we can already see here). Good to know!

Comment: "in English : K king , Q queen , R rook , B bishop , N knight. but in french : R le roi , D la dame , T la tour , F le fou , C le cavalier.." http://www.usefulchess.com/rules/notation.html, also http://www.usefulchess.com/rules/chess-pieces-names.html

Comment: I think this is a well-known open problem (apparently attributed to Tutte!). It has been discussed on MO before: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107385/a-chess-question-of-w-t-tutte/ . That question was closed, I think basically because it's a well-known open problem.

Answer (score 7):

Usually the strategy-stealing argument would go: suppose Black has a winning strategy. Then White can make an arbitrary first move, and then follow Black's winning strategy (with the adjustment that White makes an arbitrary move if the move White is suppose to make has already been played as a result of a previous arbitrary move).

However, this argument only works for games where playing an arbitrary move does not hurt you; this is not the case with chess, where zugzwang exists. So, the strategy-stealing argument does not go through.

It is mentioned in the answers to [If there is a winning strategy, is it for White?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2343/if-there-is-a-winning-strategy-is-it-for-white) that a proof of "White has a guaranteed draw or better" does not exist, and if it does, would be very difficult to find.

Comment: "this argument only works for games where playing an arbitrary move does not hurt you" --- that is not true.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Perhaps there are games where playing an arbitrary move can hurt you, but the strategy stealing can be modified in such a way that this does not end up being an issue; however, I am unaware of any such examples. Do you have one in mind?

Comment: What about chomp?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Ah, I see. That's a good example of how strategy stealing can be modified to avoid the issue of making arbitrary moves that hurt you. However, note that Chomp is not a counterexample to the claim I made in my answer: the basic "make an arbitrary move and then strategy steal" argument does not work for Chomp, since that includes the case where your arbitrary move is to take the poisoned square. I'm not saying that a modified strategy stealing argument cannot exist for chess, only that the basic one does not work.

Answer (score 4):

I think the real essence of the question is not so much in whether zugzwang exists in chess, but whether it exists in the first few (say 5) moves, and whether in that time white can effectively lose a move. I feel like the tree diagram for this shouldn't actually be that deep, if it's done in some clever way. You shouldn't have to do the whole game tree.

I'm thinking something along the lines of (assuming black can win), if the winning response to 1. e4 is e5, then the response to 1. e3 cannot also be e5, because then 2. e4 strategy steals. If you can piece together enough of those, perhaps you can prove that white can always strategy steal.

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but this seems _immensely_ unlikely and I'm a little surprised it's gotten this much positive feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The type of strategy-stealing in [chomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp) (mentioned by the OP in a comment) is exactly the one which could, in principle, be applied to chess: you don't want to neglect the first move because "it won't hurt", you actually aim at "reabsorbing" it so as to make W play exactly the same winning positions you are assuming B has at his disposal.

But, as it was said in the answer by ckefa, this, even if possible, would be very difficult. However the converse direction seems perhaps more tractable: is it possible to show that, if a winning strategy for B exists, it is **not** possible to steal it with W in the above-mentioned sense? For instance: if copying W moves as far as possible (e.g. 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nc3 Nc6 4.Be2 Be7 5. d4 d5 ecc... ) is the beginning of a winning strategy for B, it's plausible that it cannot be stolen by W.

(Of course this is of scarce practical relevance, because it seems so unlikely that B wins...but maybe it could be interesting for more abstract reasons).